# How to import knowledge base through api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-apis-explorer

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.knowledgeBases.documents/import

Consider I'm having an csv file to be imported in a cloud storage, How exactly do I execute this above API request and import the knowledge base qna's, I've added the documentation link above, I'm getting the below error too

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parent to `projects/your-project-id/knowledgeBases/xxxxxx` and import should accept it.

But I suggest to use [projects.knowledgeBases.documents.create](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.knowledgeBases.documents/create) if you are planning to create a knowledge base from scratch using a CSV file. See sample request via [projects.knowledgeBases.documents.create](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.knowledgeBases.documents/create):

```
parent: projects/your-project-id/knowledgeBases/xxxxx
importGcsCustomMetadata: false

Request Body:
{
  "contentUri": "gs://my-bucket/faq.csv",
  "displayName": "test_csv",
  "knowledgeTypes": [
    "FAQ"
  ],
  "mimeType": "text/csv"
}
```

Returns HTTP 200:

```
{
  "name": "projects/your-project-id/locations/us/operations/document-create-20210829-21261630297603-6127fbb9-0000-21dc-bec9-240588717654"
}
```

Created knowledge base in Dialogflow console:

[image]

Comment: I have the csv in azure blob

Comment: Unfortunately Google Cloud URI is only accepted for both [import](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/GcsSources) and [create](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.knowledgeBases.documents#Document).